# Predictive Model with added data

Tags: modeling, boosting

I built a predictive model in R using XGBoost to predict the success of a binary event.  All the data fed to the model is as of a single point in time, say Day 0.  How would i alter the model such that it can add in new variables once they are available, say on Day 5?  To be more specific, i am practicing model building on nfl rookie performance. My day 0 data are all prior to the season starting.  How would i "re-score" their probability for success once i get data from games played?  Do i need a whole new model?  Or do i leave those new variables as NULL in the original model?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

XGBoost isn't really set up to natively work with time-series data. Someone might have developed a clever hack to force it to do so, but it seems more appropriate to use a [time-series](/questions/tagged/time-series) model.